# Choosing between variations combinations and permuations

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

How many number can we find , that their sum of digits is equal to 6 ?

We have 3 field _ _ _;

We know that the first number cannot be 0 and has to be lower than 7 otherwise its sum wouldnt equal 6.

We are left with two field _ _ . Those numbers also has to be lower than 7 but can be 0. What do we use? Variaions combinations or permutation?

I calculated it using combinatnions using

$\frac{k+n-1}{n} = \frac{ 6 + 2 - 1}{ 2 } = \frac{7!}{(7-2)!*2!} = 21$

Is is this correct? I am still not sure when i should use combination with or w/e repeatition or something else. Could anybody explain the content of when to use what in more depth than basic?

All help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You seem to be missing some words in your first sentence.  Should it be "How many (*three digit*) numbers can we find (*such*) that their sum of digits is equal to $6$"?  Otherwise there are infinitely many numbers with sum of digits 6 if there are no other constraints.  $6, 60, 600, 6000, 60000,\dots$ for example all have sum of digits 6

Comment: Assuming that it *is* intended as such, then you essentially have the Diophantine system $\begin{cases} x+y+z=6\\ 1\leq x\\ 0\leq y\\ 0\leq z\end{cases}$ which can be transformed into the system $\begin{cases} a+b+c=5\\ 0\leq a\\ 0\leq b\\ 0\leq c\end{cases}$.  How many integer solutions to that system exist?